# SoundCloud API - Any way of extracting the genre of a track loaded in to widget?

Tags: javascript, api, widget, soundcloud

This code takes input of a SoundCloud track URL and loads it in to the widget. Is there anyway of being able to extract and display the genre/tags of this song using the SoundCloud API?

```
<html>
<head>


    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js'></script>  


</head>
<body>
    <div id="sectionLoad">

        <input type="text" id="url" value=""><br>
        <div id="gap"></div>
        <a id="loadButton" onclick="loadSong();" class="button">LOAD TRACK</a>
        <div id="gap2"></div>

        <iframe id = "sc-widget" width="80%" height="80%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=single_active=false" ></iframe>

    </div>
<script>
function loadSong(){
    (function() {

        var iframe = document.querySelector('#sc-widget');
        var widget = SC.Widget(iframe);
        var input = document.getElementById("url");

        widget.load(input.value); 
        console.log(widget);   

    }());
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the [Soundcloud widget has a getter method](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#methods), getCurrentSound(), that'll return that information for you!

Notice you'll want to call getCurrentSound() only when the widget is done loading a song, otherwise it'll return null. SC already provides a ready event, SC.Widget.Events.READY, that you can bind that to, so after `widget.load(input.value);` add this bit:

```
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function(){
    widget.getCurrentSound(function(currentSound) {
    console.log(currentSound);
    var genre = currentSound.genre;
    var tags = currentSound.tag_list;
    // add genre and tags to appropriate elements
  });
});
```

I made a jsfiddle here where I broke the getCurrentSound call out into a separate function called showSongInfo: https://jsfiddle.net/dfnny3rp/